# I want to resize any window from string variable but win32 can't get string

Tags: python-3.x, win32gui

This is code.

```
import linecache
import os
import win32gui

desktop = os.path.expanduser("~\\Desktop")

def resize_pg(N4, x, y, w, h):
    hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, N4)
    win32gui.MoveWindow(hwnd, x, y, w, h, True)
    print(N4)
    
file_path = desktop+('\Re.txt')
ref_1 = linecache.getline(file_path,1)
ref_2 = linecache.getline(file_path,2)
resize_pg(ref_1 , 0, 0, 420, 336)
```

This is data in Re.txt:

```
A.txt - Notepad
B.txt - Notepad
```

Error show:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Desktop\UUU.py", line 16, in <module>
    resize_pg(ref_1, 0, 0, 420, 336)
  File "c:\Users\Desktop\UUU.py", line 9, in resize_pg
    win32gui.MoveWindow(hwnd, x, y, w, h, True)
pywintypes.error: (1400, 'MoveWindow', 'Invalid window handle.')
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You need to debug this situation. Unfortunately, you don't have any error checking/handling in your code, so you can't tell what exactly went wrong.

At a minimum, move your `print(N4)` to the top of your `resize_pg()` function to see if you got the name of the window right. Then add `print(hwnd)` after your call to `FindWindow()` to see if the window was found.

Also, do you have the `Notepad` open with the `A.txt` file? Check the window title, is it exactly `A.txt - Notepad`? You can set up your Windows to NOT show file extensions, for example.